# How do I change a states click event dynamically in actionScript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, events, flex4, state

```
<s:Button id="btnNext" label="Next" width="80"
  click.Title="changeState('Info');"
  click.Info="changeState('Organ');"
/>
```

How do I dynamically change the "click.Title" event in actionScript?

```
btnNext.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,  ????
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
btnNext.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);

private function onClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    switch (currentState)
    {
        case "Title":
            changeState("Info");
            break;
        case "Info":
            changeState("Organ");
            break;
    }
}
```

There is no declarative states support in ActionScript.

Comment: So I see how to add an event Listener how do I remove the original event listner defined through MXML?

Comment: THere is no legal way to unsubscribe event handlers added in MXML. You can read more details [here](http://www.iampj.com/2010/03/remove-mxml-event-listeners.html). So I recommend you not to use MXML listeners if you plan to subscribe with ActionScript.